# How to add exposed custom filters in Apachesolr Views Integration

Tags: views, search

I am currently creating an application which manage a long list of persons, with a lot of fields. By doing that:

```
function creamodule_views_data_alter(&$data){
   $data['apachesolr_node']['sort_ss_availability_date'] = array(
   'title' => t('Availability Date'),
   'help' => t('Only real dates, not relative ones'),
   'sort' => array(
       'handler' => 'apachesolr_views_handler_sort',
   ),
   'argument' => array(
       'handler' => 'apachesolr_views_handler_argument',
   ),
   'filter' => array(
       'handler' => 'apachesolr_views_handler_filter',
   ),
   'field' => array(
       'handler' => 'apachesolr_views_handler_field',
   ),
   );
}
```

I am able to sort the data, but I can't filter them. The filter is available, but is broken when I select it. Does someone know how to do that, or where I can find some resources explaining how can I have this done.thank you.